# How to create array of Json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Can we make an array of list of `Json` 
For example: I have three JSON  want to convert them into array.

```js
{"region":"valore","price":"valore2"}
{"region":"valore","price":"valore2"}
{"region":"valore","price":"valore2"}
```

like

```js
[
  {"region":"valore","price":"valore2"},
  {"region":"valore","price":"valore2"},
  {"region":"valore","price":"valore2"}
]
```

Can this is Possible????

Comment: `array.push(threeJSON1);array.push(threeJSON2);array.push(threeJSON3);`

Comment: So you want to combine those three strings into one JSON? Or do you want to convert these strings into javascript objects and add them to a javascript array?

Comment: Just a note, you *do not* have JSON!  JSON is a *string format*.  JSON is a *string representation* of data, that resembles (read: is a superset of) JavaScript object syntax.  What you have are 3 *JavaScript objects*!

Comment: If you really *do* have JSON strings, you could just concat the strings together.  Or you'd can use `JSON.parse()` (and then `JSON.stringify()`) to convert the JSON into an object then create the structure you wanted.

Comment: Do you *really* have JSON or do you have three JavaScript objects?

Comment: i have JSON not Javascript object

Comment: @Pallavi: If you have JSON strings, can't you just do `var result = '[' + json1 + ','+ json2 + ']';`?

Comment: I have differentt-different JSON array collection, I want to add all JSON array inside one array. I have used array push but they make indiviual array not a whole array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with your requirements, use `array.push()` function,

```
var array = [];
jsonOne = {"region":"valore","price":"valore2"};
jsonTwo = {"region":"valore","price":"valore2"};
jsonThree = {"region":"valore","price":"valore2"};

array.push(jsonOne);
array.push(jsonTwo);
array.push(jsonThree);
```

**Update-1:**

As Azamentes pointed out in the answer, I think the following is a clean way to get your desired output mainly in your case.

```
array = [jsonOne, jsonTwo, jsonThree];
```

But if you have many number of `jsons`, you will have to loop through them or something, then `push()` function will be handy;

Comment: Why not just do `var array = [jsonOne, jsonTwo, jsonThree]'`? :)

Comment: Just a head's up -- nothing in this answer is JSON, except for your variable names.

Comment: thanks but if this json are coming from api then what to do ??

Comment: Then you might have to use `push()` function

Comment: Using `push function`, not giving the right answer which i needed

Comment: So can you show how you are implementing your code?